# Go back to parent element - CSS selector in Cypress

Tags: css-selectors, concatenation, cypress

Can someone please assist in following case:

I have to check in **if** statement does element exist. Since there is no possibility to use **Xpath** in **find** command (Throws Syntax error when run it with Xpath).

My code looks:

```
cy.xpath(list)
    .eq(index)
    .then(($el1) => {
      cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        if (
          body.find(
            currentBase +
              currentTitle[index] +
              currentExtension
          ).length > 0
        ) {
     ...
```

Where **currentBase** is Xpath before text, **currentText** - element with text and **currentExtension** is concatentation to get element below that text element.
I do not want to use those classes since they are dynamic ones (also, can not be changed with some unique attribute in near future)

And DOM looks:

[image]

Namely, easily is found marked **img** element, but with following CSS, it does not work

```
#structures img[src*="/static/media/image"].$('..').$('..').$('..') div:nth-child(2)
```

What I want is, to find **div** below element with text **Element One**

What I am doing wrong?
Or is there any other way in Cypress to use together **if** statement and to pass that step if element is not found?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. This will get you the `div` element just below `Element One` and which is also the parent element for the `img`

```js
cy.get('img[src*="/static/media/image"]').parent('div')
```

Comment: It does work. Thank you very much @Alapan Das

Comment: Yes, just have to wait few minutes, already tried

Comment: @Alapan Just to understand. I see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector and in other places that there is not way to go up to a parent element with CSS selectors. What is the difference?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you can read this https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parent. `parent` is a cypress command, that is designed to do specifically the task you were looking for. If you want to learn more about it, I have written a blog on this topic which you can also look at, if you would be interested - https://testersdock.com/cypress-parents-parent-children/

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. No, I do not have any relation to cypress, making automation mostly with Java and Python. I thought there is a way to do such CSS Selector. As I know it's impossible.